# Scoped dependency use from NServiceBus Behavior

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nservicebus

I'm trying to use a `Scoped` dependency from a NServiceBus `Behavior`.

From [NServiceBus Behavior](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/manipulate-with-behaviors) docs:

> Behaviors are only created once and the same instance is reused on
>   every invocation of the pipeline. Consequently, every behavior
>   dependency will also behave as a singleton, even if a different option
>   was specified when registering it in dependency injection.
>   Furthermore, the behavior, and all dependencies called during the
>   invocation phase, need to be concurrency safe and possibly stateless.
>   Storing state in a behavior instance should be avoided since it will
>   cause the state to be shared across all message handling sessions.
>   This could lead to unwanted side effects.

Since a `Behavior` is a Singleton and the `Invoke` method of the `Behavior` doesn't allow to inject any dependency (such as the `invoke` method of a net core middleware because in this case it's a regular interface implementation), I can't use a `scoped` dependency from here.

I've tried to resolve my dependencies in my `Invoke` method for each incoming/outgoing message by passing IServiceCollection in the constructor:

```
private readonly IServiceCollection _services;

public MyIncomingMessageBehavior(IServiceCollection services)
{
    _services = services;
}

public override async Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
{
    var myScopedDependency = _services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IMyScopedDependency>();
    // always 
}
```

[But this doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949305/why-does-scoped-service-resolve-as-two-different-instances-for-same-request):

> That's because when you inject IServiceProvider into your middleware -
>   that's "global" provider, not request-scoped. There is no request when
>   your middleware constructor is invoked (middleware is created once at
>   startup), so it cannot be request-scoped container.

In summary, my scoped dependency contains data for the current context and I'd like to access this data from the `Invoke` method of my `Behavior` singleton?

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a scope before resolving your dependency:

```
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

public MyIncomingMessageBehavior(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
}

public override async Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
{
    using(var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var myScopedDependency = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedDependency>();
    }
}
```

Also, pay attention that your dependency is disposed along with scope.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to build a new service provider one _each call_ to the middleware. This means you are creating a new container on _every_ incoming message. The creation of a service provider, however, has a performance penalty, just as the first resolve of a certain dependency has. On top of that, every service provider has its own set of singleton instances, causing registered singletons to behave as _scoped_ dependencies, which is typically not what you want.

Comment: @Steven, you're right, I've updated the answer, now there shouldn't be that issue

Comment: Thumbs up and +1 from me.

Comment: Although it can be implied, it would be good, though, to make clear in the example that the `IMyScopedDependency` dependency is used within that scope, because it will be released/decomposed when the `using` block ends.

Comment: This creates a scope for my invoke method. I don't want to stablish a new scope here, I want to access/resolve a scoped dependency that it was created for the current HttpContext. This HttpContext sends a new message and I expected to access to a service of this scope. I hope I have explained well.

Comment: @Alpha75 I'm afraid, Behavior lives out of your request scope, so it is not possible to resolve the scoped dependency with value that was created for HttpContext.

Comment: Finally I will move my data from one context to other using headers when I send or publish. Maybe I could decorate IMessageSession to pass always my HttpContext headers to NServiceBus headers. However, I've created the scoped dependency that you have proposed to maintain certain data to be thread safe.